# SQL Sort By Index sum from Multiple Results By Adding Index corresponding to the same key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficulty sorting results of multiple queries. The queries I'm running return a sorted list with zipcode as the key. So, for example, 1 query will return sorted zipcodes where crime rate is low, with lowest zipcode having a 1 as its index, then a query that returns zipcodes where average salary is over 100k or less with closest to 100k being index of 1.

Say I have 6 or more similar queries. How can I then sort zipcodes by sum of indices from all queries?

Example queries im running :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.Zip_Code, s1.Median_Value
FROM NJ_Housing_Expenses s1, NJ_Housing_Expenses s2
WHERE s1.Median_Value < 100000 AND s1.Zip_Code NOT IN (
SELECT Zip_Code
FROM NJ_Housing_Expenses
WHERE Median_Value = 0
)
ORDER BY Median_Value DESC
```

and

```
SELECT City, (((Violent_Crime*4) + Property_Crime)/Population) as CrimeSum
From NJ_Crime_Statistics
where Date = 2016
Group By City
Order by CrimeSum ASC
```

OUTPUT

```
1 08754   
2 08234
3 07332
4 09563
```

then

```
1 08754
2 07332
3 09563
4 08234
```

Then is sorted by adding index

```
1 08754 (2)
2 07332 (5)
3 08234 (6)
4 09563 (7)
```

Comment: please start [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your post for readability and more responses

Comment: Your second query uses `City`, not `Zip_Code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to "number" the rows in each query. We could use a MySQL user-defined variable to do that.

We can wrap a suitable query in parens, and reference it as an inline view (in place of a table).  As a demonstration.

```
SELECT q1.Zip_code
     , @q1_rn := @q1_rn + 1   AS rn 
  FROM ( SELECT @q1_rn := 0 ) i 
 CROSS
  JOIN (
         -- source query here as inline view
         SELECT s1.Zip_Code
              , ...
           FROM ...
          ORDER BY Median_Value DESC
       ) q1
 ORDER BY q1.Median_Value DESC
```

We can do the same thing for another query, but use a different user-defined variable

```
SELECT q2.Zip_code
     , @q2_rn := @q2_rn + 1   AS rn
  FROM ( SELECT @q2_rn := 0 ) i 
 CROSS
  JOIN (
         -- inline view query here
       ) q2
 ORDER BY q2.CrimeSum ASC
```

---

We can combine the results of those queries with a `UNION ALL` set operator, and reference that whole thing as an inline view,

```
 SELECT t.Zip_code 
      , SUM(t.rn)   AS tot_rn
   FROM (
           (  
              -- first query from above goes here
           )
           UNION ALL
           (
              -- second query from above goes here
           )
           UNION ALL
           (
              -- third query
           )
           UNION ALL
           (
              -- fourth query
           )
        ) t
  GROUP BY t.Zip_code
  ORDER BY tot_rn ASC
```

Add a `GROUP BY` to collapse all of the rows with the same `Zip_Code` (the first column returned by each of the source queries... each query should return exactly two columns... `Zip_code` and `rn`.

We use a `SUM()` aggregate to total up the values of `rn`, giving a total for each `Zip_Code`.